# MariaDB Galera Cluster not replicate data after crash

Tags: replication, mariadb, database-replication, galera

I setup galera cluster on two different server and sync them as a master-master replication.

**SERVER CONFIGURATION**

Debian GNU/Linux 7
500 GB HDD

Lets say example i have two servers. Server A and Server B

**ISSUE**

Now due to some reason if server A Mysql crashed or Server Down that time complete traffic managed by Server B and it log data on B
server A and server B are in master-master replication so both node are masters.

Now the problem is when A was down and the data which inserted on B that's replicate on A completely fine when A is UP but the data is not sync which perform update operation on B in absence of A.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or is there any configuration that resolved my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical split-brain scenario.

What is happening is that your cluster can not determine which one is the primary node. You can read more about it [here](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/twonode.html).

To prevent this from happening in the future you should make sure that you have a uneven number of nodes in your cluster, or use a [Galera Arbitrator](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/arbitrator.html).

I hope this was helpful. Good luck!

Comment: @mrb we are having 2 servers in the replication(even number), do you mean we need to add some dummy server to avoid this issue again? is this issue common?

Comment: @Devang. The problem with even numbers is that they cannot determine which of the two servers is the 'primary' node after a node failure. Adding a third node to the cluster can solve this. You can find all the information here: http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/twonode.html.

Comment: @Devang, yes the problem is very common because your application is very dependent on the network. And we all know that a network is not 100% reliable. You could read the CAP Theorem of Dr Eric Brewer if you want to know more about it. :)

Comment: @H.Patel I know that Server A is your primary node. But Server A and Server B cannot determine after a crash which one of them has latest version of the data and therefore they cannot decide which one is the primary component. By adding a Galera Arbitrator or a third node you can solve this problem. They just need some 3rd party helping them out with the vote (quorum calculation).

Comment: Maybe this explains the split-brain and quorum calculations a bit better: http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/weightedquorum.html.